# Topological Hochschild homology using equivariant orthogonal spectra

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, algebraic-k-theory

In the Hesselholt-Madsen paper ["On the K-theory of finite algebras over Witt vectors of perfect fields"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938396000031), the authors develop some results concerning the Topological Hochschild homology (THH) of functors with smash products.

They use the language of equivariant spectra in the sense of [Lewis-May-Steinberger](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0075778).

<s>My question is if there is a more modern reformulation of this work using equivariant orthogonal spectra (or other (one-categorical) variants)</s>.

I am quite certain that using the results from [Mandell, May, Schwede and Shipley](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/mmssLMSDec30.pdf), one can translate the results  from Hesselholt-Madsen to orthogonal  spectra. My Question then is if this has already been done. At this moment, I am not looking for an infinity categorical treatment.

To be more precise, I would like to see the construction of THH and topological cyclic homology using orthogonal spectra. 
Preferably I would like to see the construction of the Tate spectral sequence as well, where for a  finite cyclic group $C$ and $T$ an equivariant $C$ spectrum, the Tate spectral sequence is 
$$E^2_{r,s}=\hat{H}^{-r}(C,\pi_sT)\Rightarrow \pi_{r+s}\hat{\mathbb{H}}(C,T),$$

where the $E^2$ page is the ordinary Tate cohomology of $C$  and  $E^{\infty}$-page is the homotopy groups of the Tate spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

This has a partial positive answer.

The theory of cyclotomic spectra using orthogonal spectra is developed in 'The homotopy theory of cyclotomic spectra' by Blumberg and Mandell. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1694.

Moreover, Nikolaus and Scholze have an exposition of the Böckstedt construction of THH using orthogonal spectra in their paper 'On topological cyclic homology'. 
See https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01799.